# Windows remote desktop goes blank on miminize

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, vnc

I have a few users that connect to my server via vnc and share the desktop to work together on a few things work related. I stay connected via remote desktop and they might continue working on our issues. When it is minimized, after a few seconds, the desktop on their side goes black. The only way that I can keep it from going black is to keep it maximized so they can continue to work.

Any way to prevent this from happening? I tried join.me and vnc and it does the same thing for both apps.

Thanks!

Comment: Why vnc ? Why not creating them their own windows account to allow them to rdp in. Collab when you minimize on your side is no longer collab

Comment: I need to interact with the user. The programs and files are under my user and they need to be able to access them when needed.

Comment: What are the system specs that you are sharing from? What type of graphics card and how much graphics RAM.

Comment: It's a Hyper-V virtual machine running windows 2012R2 with 32gb of ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is by design. As you minimize your RDP session it won't receive a screen refresh. 
You could try to install a VNC server onto the server and enable multiple login as described in https://superuser.com/questions/887406/vnc-two-users-at-same-time.

> Multiple users can connect to a VNC server but that requires you to modify some options in the 'expert tab' of VNC server. so assuming that you are using a recent version of the Real VNC, to allow concurrent connections do the followings:

- Search for the "AlwaysShared" and set it to "true"
- Search for the "NeverShared" and set it to "false"

> after doing them click "apply" to save the settings.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem exists due to the tight connection between RDP and the Server Session. The first thing I would try is to use VNC to connect to the Server instead of RDP, then log in, creating your session. Then allow the others to connect. This should sever the tie between the state of the window on your system and the display from the session on the server.

My organization no longer uses VNC, so I can't test this directly, but it works this way with TeamViewer.

Hope this helps.